# How should I share Files using WiFi Direct to another android device?? - Salut and LoganSquare

Tags: android, android-wifi, wifi-direct, file-sharing, logan-square

**

> **SITUATION IS -**

**

1. I am creating an application that shares files between android devices.
2. I use [Salut](https://github.com/markrjr/Salut) as a WiFi Direct Wrapper.
3. Salut uses [LoganSquare](https://github.com/bluelinelabs/LoganSquare) for sharing data between peers connected via WiFi Direct.

> **My Objective** : **How should I share *Files* using WiFi Direct to another android device??**

Some what like ShareIt, Superbeam, Xender etc..

(It is my project to create, process a file, and send it over WiFi to peers.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, for devs facing similar issues. I figured out the answer.

Salut works well with LoganSquare except that it needs data to be serialized to send to other devices. To send files, we can contain them in a [seralizable](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjbjv336a3TAhWLgbwKHWkKCEsQFggmMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2Ftutorial%2Fjndi%2Fobjects%2Fserial.html&usg=AFQjCNFO_pOSB0PXilw8NjRQEbaytXDazA&sig2=H7xOZh3FYQiWLAFhVne8eA) class as a String field of the class as Strings are serializable.

HOW TO DO THAT?

1. Load the file in [FileOutputStream](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=12&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiFi6CV6q3TAhUBgrwKHfMKDTYQFghTMAs&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdocs.oracle.com%2Fjavase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2Fjava%2Fio%2FFileOutputStream.html&usg=AFQjCNFhMYX9jCtgJUewHLfAhdUbNqgLSw&sig2=syhqwKnszif-31b8lLK6gg)
2. Convert it to [ByteArrayOutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36404949/is-possible-to-convert-fileoutputstream-to-byte-array)
3. Then convert it to **String**

BUT I HAVE A **HUGE** file! How much would the capacity of the String be?

**No worries!**

[String can store up to (2^31)-1 characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1179996/5852891) (Integer.MAX_VALUE)

Calculations -

1. (2^31)-1 = 2,147,483,648 characters
2. [Assuming Java takes 2 bytes for a character :](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5078365/5852891) 
   2,147,483,648 characters = 2,147,483,648/2 = 1,073,741,824 bytes = 1,048,576 KB = 1024 MB = **1 GB**

(or simple 1KB = 2^10 bytes , 1MB = 2^20 bytes, 1GB = 2^30 bytes )

**Are you going to send a file more than 1 GB size ?**

If yes, you can use a String[ ].

**Problems on security ?**

You can [encrypt](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjTttft7K3TAhWBa7wKHQiEAO4QFggnMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.developer.com%2Fws%2Fandroid%2Fencrypting-with-android-cryptography-api.html&usg=AFQjCNGMuZWQVOepJCSRygVQ1Fe1U4IRLQ&sig2=xsUslsSR1Dk6dTb8O5Bb-w) the file before sending !